# Airflow - how to send email based on operator result?

Tags: airflow

I have a python script that is called from `BashOperator`.
The scripts return can return statuses `0` or `1`.

I want to trigger email only when the status `1`.
Note these statuses are not to be confused with `Failure`/`Success`. This is simply an indication that something was changed with the data and requires attention from the developer.

This is my operator:

```
t = BashOperator(task_id='import',
                 bash_command="python /home/ubuntu/airflow/scripts/import.py",
                 dag=dag)
```

I looked over the docs but all email related addressed the issue of `On Failure` which is irrelevant in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to override an operator or anything fancy, you might be able to use Xcoms and the BranchPythonOperator

If your condition is based on a `0` or a `1`, you can just push that value to XCom (set [xcom_push](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L42) to True).

Then, you can use the PythonBranchOperator to check that value, and use that value to execute the appropriate task. You can find an example of the [BranchPythonOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py) and [pulling from XCom](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py) in the Airflow example_dags.

Comment: Nice. how do I send the return value in xcom?

Comment: You should just be able to set `xcom_push` to `True` when initializing your `BashOperator`